# App crashes when using Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, crash, sharedpreferences

Im making a simple app, which counts the clicks of a button and saves the integer with a Shared Preferences. I tried it with the following code, but the app crashes all the time, if I try to open "Singleplayer"

```
public class Singleplayer extends AppCompatActivity {

private int sp1;
private int record;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_singleplayer);


    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonspieler1);
    final TextView lbl1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblspieler1);
    final TextView lbl2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblrekord);

    SharedPreferences data_record = getSharedPreferences("savegame", 0);
    record = data_record.getInt("myKey1", 0);
    lbl2.setText(String.valueOf(record));

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {


            if(sp1< record) {
                sp1++;
                lbl1.setText(String.valueOf(sp1));
            }
            else if(sp1>= record)
            {
                sp1++;
                record++;
                lbl1.setText(String.valueOf(sp1));
                lbl2.setText(String.valueOf(record));

            }


        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences data_record = getSharedPreferences("savegame", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data_record.edit();
    editor.putString("myKey1", String.valueOf(record));
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Please read: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using sharedPrefrence in your `onStop()` so you will face many issue here, i suggest to use it at the end of click method

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {


            if(sp1< record) {
                sp1++;
                lbl1.setText(String.valueOf(sp1));
            }
            else if(sp1>= record)
            {
                sp1++;
                record++;
                lbl1.setText(String.valueOf(sp1));
                lbl2.setText(String.valueOf(record));

            }

SharedPreferences data_record = getSharedPreferences("savegame", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data_record.edit();
    editor.putString("myKey1", String.valueOf(record));
    editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

so why the app crash, because the sharedPref dosen't carry any value it's **null**

please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I changed `private int record;` to `private Integer record;` and it works now perfectly